# In Ubuntu Python 2.7 reading output of an os.system() command

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04, python-2.7, os.system

So I am running code that looks like this on Ubuntu 11.4 and Python 2.7:

```
p_scan_command = "sudo nmap -sC -sV -PN -O 192.168.0.1/24"
time.sleep(1.5)
os.system(p_scan_command)
f = open('nmapscan1.log', 'r')
print f.read()
f.close()
```

What is happening is that I end up with no results, and the scan is not being run, probably because it is being run with 'sudo'. I want to know

1. If I have been correct in my diagnosis of the problem and
2. How to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Are you sure that the log file is even created? I cannot see where this name is mentionned - but maybe it is created by default.
2. Are you asked for the password by `sudo`?
   This could tell you if sudo is really run.
3. `os.system` is kind of deprecated or at least frowned upon; better use `subprocess.call()`, `subprocess.check_call()` or `subprocess.Popen()` (gives you an object which you can use to further control the process).

---

EDIT: Just tested. Here the scan runs, but the output gets displayed instead of written to a file. Probably you are missing the `> nmapscan1.log` part in the `os.system()` call.

With `subprocess`, you would write

```
sp = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'nmap', '-sC', '-sV', '-PN', '-O', '192.168.0.1/24'],
    stdout=file("nmapscan1.log", "w"))
sp.wait()
f = open('nmapscan1.log', 'r')
print f.read()
f.close()
```

or if you don't need the file, simply

```
sp = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'nmap', '-sC', '-sV', '-PN', '-O', '192.168.0.1/24'],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print sp.stdout.read()
sp.wait()
```

Comment: Right. The OP should not really be using `os.system` for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `commands` module in python.
2. You can use `subprocess` module.

The main issue is when use `sudo` command inside `python` program  doesn't ask for password, so better run `sudo python filename.py`